# Test all possible combinations of rows

Tags: java, arrays, search, comparison

The problem is the following. There are multiple rows that have non-unique identifiers:

```
id value
0: {1,2,3}
0: {1,2,2}

1: {1,2,3}

2: {1,2,3}
2: {1,1,3}
```

I have the function `equals` that can compare multiple rows between each other. I need to write a code that selects the rows as an input of the function `equals`. The rows selected must have unique ids, BUT I should check all possible combinations of unique ids. For instance, if there are 5 rows with ids: 0,0,1,2,3, then I should check the following two combinations of ids: 0,1,2,3 and 0,1,2,3, because 0 apears twice. Of course, each of these two combinations will consist of unique rows that have id=0.

My code snippet is the following:

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
  ArrayList<Row> allRows = new ArrayList<Row>();
  allRows.add(new Row(0,new int[]{1,2,3}));
  allRows.add(new Row(0,new int[]{1,2,2}));
  allRows.add(new Row(1,new int[]{1,2,3}));
  allRows.add(new Row(2,new int[]{1,2,3}));
  allRows.add(new Row(2,new int[]{1,1,3}));

  boolean answer = hasEqualUniqueRows(allRows);
}

private boolean hasEqualUniqueRows(ArrayList<Row> allTokens) {
    for (int i=0; i<allTokens.size(); i++) {
        ArrayList<Integer[]> rows = new ArrayList<Integer[]>();
        rows = findUniqueRows(i,allTokens);
        boolean answer = equalsExceptForNulls(rows);
        if (answer) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
// Compare rows for similarities
public static <T> boolean equalsExceptForNulls(ArrayList<T[]> ts) {
    for (int i=0; i<ts.size(); i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<ts.size(); j++) {
            if (i != j) {
                boolean answer = equals(ts.get(i),ts.get(j));
                if (!answer) return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public static <T> boolean equals(T[] ts1, T[] ts2) {
    if (ts1.length != ts2.length) return false;
    for(int i = 0; i < ts1.length; i++) {
       T t1 = ts1[i], t2 = ts2[i];
       if (t1 != null && t2 != null && !t1.equals(t2)) 
           return false;
    }
    return true;
}

class Row {
          private String key;
          private Integer[] values;

      public Row(String k,Integer[] v) {
          this.key = k;
          this.values = v;
      }

      public String getKey() {
          return this.key;
      }

      public Integer[] getValues() {
          return this.values;
      }
}
```

}

Since the number of rows with unique ids is apriori unknown, I don´t know how to solve this problem. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Edit#1
I updated the code. Now it´s more complete. But it lacks the implementation of the function `findUniqueRows`. This function should select rows from the ArrayList that have unique keys (ids). Could someone help me to develop this function? Thanks.

Comment: *"Any suggestions?"*  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  BTW - is this homework?

Comment: No, it´s not a homework. The problem with posting SSCCE is that my current version of the function ´equals´ works with 3 rows as an input. Therefore, I cannot post it here. I´m waiting for code snippets or suggestions how to select combinations of rows step-by-step. Maybe someone can provide conceptual solution?

Comment: I would use a strategy which only generates unique combinations, this way you can avoid the need to find and remove duplicates.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey: The problem is that I cannot avoid non-unique identifiers of rows. That´s the point of my issue.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to do. You need unique ids and rows? What's the expected output for your example? I'd start with implementing hashCode for Row class and try to use HashMap or HashSet. First-remove duplicates (same id and content) and then find Rows with same content int the set that left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the objective is to find every combination without duplicates you can do this with the following.  The test to find duplicates is just to confirm it doesn't generate any duplicates in the first place.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        Bag<Integer> b = new Bag<>();
        b.countFor(1, 2);
        b.countFor(2, 1);
        b.countFor(3, 3);
        Set<String> set = new LinkedHashSet<>();
        for (List<Integer> list : b.combinations()) {
            System.out.println(list);
            String s = list.toString();
            if (!set.add(s))
                System.err.println("Duplicate entry " + s);
        }
    }
}

class Bag<E> {
    final Map<E, AtomicInteger> countMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    void countFor(E e, int n) {
        countMap.put(e, new AtomicInteger(n));
    }

    void decrement(E e) {
        AtomicInteger ai = countMap.get(e);
        if (ai.decrementAndGet() < 1)
            countMap.remove(e);
    }

    void increment(E e) {
        AtomicInteger ai = countMap.get(e);
        if (ai == null)
            countMap.put(e, new AtomicInteger(1));
        else
            ai.incrementAndGet();
    }

    List<List<E>> combinations() {
        List<List<E>> ret = new ArrayList<>();
        List<E> current = new ArrayList<>();
        combinations0(ret, current);
        return ret;
    }

    private void combinations0(List<List<E>> ret, List<E> current) {
        if (countMap.isEmpty()) {
            ret.add(new ArrayList<E>(current));
            return;
        }
        int position = current.size();
        current.add(null);
        List<E> es = new ArrayList<>(countMap.keySet());
        if (es.get(0) instanceof Comparable)
            Collections.sort((List) es);
        for (E e : es) {
            current.set(position, e);
            decrement(e);
            combinations0(ret, current);
            increment(e);
        }
        current.remove(position);
    }
}
```